# Unable to add default on update constraint on Date column

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to default the last_modified_date column's value on every update to sysdate.
Oracle is throwing 'Missing Keyword' exception when I am running the DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE releaser_queue  
    (id                            Number GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    processed_date                 DATE,
    last_modified_date             DATE default on UPDATE sysdate, -- throwing exception
    created_date                   DATE default on null sysdate, 
    time_elapsed                   TIMESTAMP
    )
```

I expect the table to be created but Oracle is throwing ORA-00905 Missing keyword exception on UPDATE keyword

Comment: Looks like there is no ON UPDATE in Oracle, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56900/add-column-on-update-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `DEFAULT ON UPDATE`, at least up [through version 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6). But you can accomplish your goal using a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RELEASER_QUEUE_BU
  BEFORE UPDATE ON RELEASER_QUEUE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE := COALESCE(:NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, SYSDATE);
END RELEASER_QUEUE_BU;
```